# Access control JAX-RS application

Tags: jax-rs, restful-authentication

I have a JAX-RS application deployed under tomcat and a mobile app.
I would like to know how to make the webservice usable only by the mobile application, in other words, allow access only for a given application

Answer (score 0):

When a request comes in across the internet, there's not really a safe way to be sure what application sent the request.  Applications can identify themselves however they want.  You could, if you want, attempt to hide credentials in your application, somehow, and have it log in with those credentials.  But if anyone discovers those credentials, they can write a program that uses them to pretend to the your application.  The problem is that you cannot count on any control over the client system.  The client system can always be altered to pretend to be something it is not.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, you can add username/encrypted password in the invoke request, and then compare it with the ones saved in the server side

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to, you could implement some form of cryptography. For example, the JAX-RS service can send a 401 forbidden and provide a nonce for the client to sign with its private key, and then send back to the server in the Authorization header. Otherwise, stick to HTTP authentication. If you are communicating via HTTPS, you should be fine with basic auth.